# Measure ball's acceleration down inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, experimental-physics, friction, home-experiment

If I am asked to devise an experiment to find an expression for the acceleration of a uniform sphere (ball bearing) rolling down an inclined plane, as a function of the angle of incline. Hence deduce 
the value of $g$ within 1%.

How would I do this accurately using simple equipment such as rulers and stopwatches? I.e without motion capture or breaker circuits? I think [this method](http://www.luc.edu/faculty/dslavsk/courses/ntsc395/homework/ntsc395speedandacceleration.pdf) will suffice, but is there a way to account for the error more precisely?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: This is not homework

Comment: "I think this method will suffice, but is there a way to account for the error more precisely?" I'm not sure what you mean by 'to account for the error'. An experiment needs to be sufficiently accurate in order to draw meaningful conclusions from it. Lower measuring error will lead to higher confidence intervals regarding your conclusions. Your selected method *seems* suitable as a starting point, though.

Answer (score 2):

I gather that the large source of error you are worried about is the ability of the experimenter to accurately hit the start/stop button on the stopwatch at the start/stop of the ball's journey down the ramp.

### What *is* the approximate magnitude of error we'd expect?

Before I directly answer your question, let's estimate how bad the experimental error will be (reasonably close, without actually doing the experiment).

Typical human reaction time is 2-3 tenths of a second, somewhat increasing with age. I would expect the error to be smaller at the top of the ramp (easier to synchronize with "3..2..1..go!"). I would also expect the experimenter to be able to somewhat anticipate when the ball will reach the end of the ramp (because they can see the ball rolling towards it), and these timings may even somewhat cancel each other out. So for argument's sake (not to be used as an actual estimate; that's what *science* is for), let's be optimistic and say the total amount of reaction error would be around 100ms. For a typical length of ramp used in such an experiment, ball bearing travel times would be on the order of 1 second (1000ms).

Thus, your reaction error is:

$\frac{val_{exp} - val_{known}}{val_{known}} = \frac{(1000+100)ms - 1000ms}{1000ms} = 10\%$

**Note:** When applied to a calculation of g, the above error will actually be *worse,* on the order of $g \pm 17\%$, left as an exercise to the reader to verify.

So, yes, a 10% error is far from your desired 1%. Can we do better?

### Use a longer ramp or a shallower incline

You'd think you could just use a longer ramp or a shallower incline. Unfortunately, to get < 1% error with a 100ms (total) error, you need a 10 second roll, the length of ramp required with a shallow ($10^{\circ}$) incline is given by:

$s = v_{i}t + \frac{1}2at^2$ but since $v_{i} = 0$,

$s = \frac{1}2at^2$

And we know $t = 10 sec$ and $a = g * \sin \theta = 9.81m/s^2 * \sin 10^{\circ} = 1.703m/s^2$

$s = 85.15 m$

I imagine that ramp length would have several practical limitations.

### Can we do better?

Unfortunately, not much. Given the constraints in the question regarding "ordinary" measurements with rulers and stopwatches, a typical classroom experiment of this type will have a fairly large error. Using many trials and some statistical analysis (if this is a senior high school or university-level experiment) to get a confidence interval for your experimental value might improve the *analysis,* but not the actual *error.* Put another way, no math is capable of going back in time and pushing that stopwatch button for the experimenter. Plus, you asked how to improve the experiment, not the analysis.

However, as a teaching tool, that error is actually a rather valuable part of the experiment. It's one of those rare experiments where the value you're trying to measure (g) is very well known, and the sources of error are at the same time significant, but also easy to imagine, and not too difficult to estimate.

Remember, science isn't just about results. It's about questions. (Right, well, tell that to my grant application reviewers.)

Comment: According to my university, it is possible to get within 1%. Perhaps the method I linked is wrong

Comment: With enough careful trials, you might get an average *value* within 1% of 9.81 m/s^2 (or whatever g is where you live), but getting a 1% *error* is another thing, without some mechanical assistance with timing. A 1% error in timing (note since it's $t^2$ in the equation, it's actually even harder) for a 1 second travel time is 10ms, or 0.01 seconds, or (mean) 0.005sec per button press. Some of the best precision button pushers in the world (competitive video gamers) cannot reliably do "frame perfect" inputs, which have a required precision of about 0.017 sec, after months to years of practice.

Comment: If the reaction error was 100ms, how does that impact the deduced value of g? Why is 'average value' different?

Comment: With a ~1 second roll, a 100ms total timing error would result in approximately 17% error (see my updated answer). The value you get in your experiment (an average of the trials) is meaningless without knowing the precision (error) of that number. Let's say your trials average out to exactly 9.811m/s^2 in Seattle. That's great, right? You're within 1% of the known value, right? Unfortunately, no. What was your error? A 10% error (for example) in g means your value is $9.811 \pm 0.981 m/s^2$. That means the *real* value could be 8.83 or 10.79, or anything in between. You can't say for sure.

Comment: Also, when you are finding $g$, be careful not to conclude anything based on the "known" value of $g$! This may sound strange, but (virtually always) experiments do not succeed or fail based on how close they come to an accepted value in a book. Instead, experiments' success is based on the design, apparatus, and accurate performance of said experiment. If your well-designed experiment finds $g = 8.0 \pm 0.01 m/s^2$, and that experiment was repeatable by anyone, then you *must* conclude that the accepted value is wrong!